# Illustrator opens files in RGB/GPU Preview

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I've downloaded a SVG file from a free online source. Upon opening it in Illustrator I cannot edit the SVG but on top of my tab it says: (RGB/GPU Preview):

[image]

I am a little confused when I open every file I am not able to edit it. Am I doing something wrong here or ss the file edit prohibited by the author?

Comment: That has nothing to do with why you can not edit it its just telling you what visual mode you are in. No most likely the thing is just grouped.

Comment: I do not think there is anything wrong with the file.  I think everything may be joined and you are unaware of how to edit files.  Do you know what anchor points are?

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, cmd-y switches from Preview to work mode and vice versa.

Comment: If by "work mode" you mean *Outline Mode* then yes, CMD+Y switches the views, but this still doesn't address the issue raised in your question, nor does it answer it.  Outline mode is just used to more easily see the different paths that make up your document.  I personally have never used it, so I wouldn't consider it Work Mode. As Joojaa said, don't worry about the mode you're in and instead pay more attention to how the document is structured.  Groups, Clipping Masks, locked layers, etc. could all be factors.